# What are the best ways to update an image url available in the sql database of my Android app

Tags: android, sql, kotlin

I have a database name as userinfo.sql in my res of the Android. It has the user profile URL as imageUrl as Text. Currently it is `https://userdatabase1.com/username`. I need to change this to the `https://usetdatabase2.com/userimage.`.

What are the easy ways and the best way to achieve this?

Comment: In your res? Where exactly?

Comment: res/raw/userinfo.sql

Comment: Files in res/raw are resource files and read only for your app.  So not achievable.

Comment: @blackapps Any other ways

Comment: Your app can in no way modify that resource file.

Comment: @blackapps I just editted the image URL as I need and install the app freshly. it works fine. But If I have the already installed app, it not refreshing  Any way to update this?

Comment: Your app can in no way update that resource file.

Comment: I have updated the raw. Why you are misleading. I have updated the SQL database URL value